# What's the Babel translit key?

Tags: babel, transliteration

I've noticed that, in Greek,

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

gets mapped to

```
alpha beta fsigma delta epsilon phi gamma eta iota theta kappa lambda mu nu omicron pi chi rho sigma tau upsilon (nothing) omega xi psi zeta
```

What's it like for Russian, Arabic, etc.? I'm too lazy to type in the actual characters.

Comment: This is a non-standard feature (or misfeature, imho) in Greek based on a trick. In 8-bit engines it uses a font encoding (LGR) which contains, say, the glyph ‘µ’ instead of ‘m’ at the corresponding ASCII slot. Other languages are based on macros; eg, in Russian `\cyrd` is ‘д’.

Comment: @JavierBezos Interesting.

Comment: For cyrillic, there's an input scheme based on the Math. Reviews transliteration.  It's rather old, and requires the OT2 encoding, but can still be used.  The input scheme is described in the `amsfonts` user's guide, `texdoc amsfndoc`, on p.17.